# align all float:left vertically

Tags: css-float

[image: CSS]

[image: CSS 2]

image 1 shows my site template

`image 2 is my problem`

all elements on the right side are floats.

the `sign in` image has this:

```
#h2 {
margin:0;
padding:0;
float:right;
padding-top:8px;
padding-right:122px;
}
```

sidebar - the green colored box has this :

```
sidebar {
background:green;
float:right;
width:238px;
height:240px;
clear:both;
margin-right:12px;
```

I cannot remove the space between the green and image sign-in.

Comment: Please post HTML code or create a fiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: http://pastebin.com/mR4dVQcU - HTML 
http://pastebin.com/rA4kuCWX - CSS